# WordPressでマルチ言語を出し分けるphpコード

Tags: php, wordpress

```
<p>
    <?php
        echo sprintf( esc_attr__( 'Hello %s%s%s (not %2$s? %sSign out%s)', 'woocommerce' ), '<strong>', esc_html( $current_user->display_name ), '</strong>', '<a href="' . esc_url( wc_get_endpoint_url( 'customer-logout', '', wc_get_page_permalink( 'myaccount' ) ) ) . '">', '</a>' );
?>
</p>
<p>
    <?php
        echo sprintf( esc_attr__( 'From your account dashboard you can view your %1$srecent orders%2$s, manage your %3$sshipping and billing addresses%2$s and %4$sedit your password and account details%2$s.', 'woocommerce' ), '<a href="' . esc_url( wc_get_endpoint_url( 'orders' ) ) . '">', '</a>', '<a href="' . esc_url( wc_get_endpoint_url( 'edit-address' ) ) . '">', '<a href="' . esc_url( wc_get_endpoint_url( 'edit-account' ) ) . '">' );
?>
</p>
```

現在wordpressでマルチ言語対応のECサイトを作成しているのですが、dashboard画面に表示されるはずのセカンダリ言語が、上記のようにデフォルト言語で表示されてしまっています。（サイト内でこの文言だけ）

正しくセカンダリ言語を表示させるため、このphpコードに命令文を加え、上記コード内に2言語記述するという方法でどうにか実装出来ないかと考えていますが当方phpの知識がありません。
get_locale(); 等のようにif/elseでの出し分けが出来れば嬉しいです。

説明が分かりにくかったらすみません。
どうぞよろしくお願いします。

*** 追記 ***

```
<?php
    if ($locale == "ja") {
        echo sprintf( esc_attr__( 'こんにちは %s%s%s (%2$s でない場合は %sサインアウト %s)', 'woocommerce' ), '<strong>', esc_html( $current_user->display_name ), '</strong>', '<a href="' . esc_url( wc_get_endpoint_url( 'customer-logout', '', wc_get_page_permalink( 'myaccount' ) ) ) . '">', '</a>' );
    } else {
        echo sprintf( esc_attr__( 'Hello %s%s%s (not %2$s? %sSign out%s)', 'woocommerce' ), '<strong>', esc_html( $current_user->display_name ), '</strong>', '<a href="' . esc_url( wc_get_endpoint_url( 'customer-logout', '', wc_get_page_permalink( 'myaccount' ) ) ) . '">', '</a>' );
    }
?>
```

上記のように2言語仕様に変更してみましたが、やはりデフォルトしか表示されず、でした。サイト大改造中でアップデート出来ていなかったのですがこのために、一時的にプラグイン更新しました。
お時間のある方、よろしければ上記コードのどこが実装に足りないのか教えて頂けたら幸いです。

```
<?php $locale = get_locale(); ?>
<?php if ('ja' == $locale  ) : ?>
    //デフォルト
<?php else: ?>
    //セカンダリ
<?php endif; ?>
```

ちなみに、header.phpでも近い方法を取っているんですが、そちらは上記の記述で適用出来ています。
ですが、当該箇所はこの記述では反映してくれませんでした。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 上記のように、の指すものがよくわかりません…………(当該の出力を貼ってください)

Comment: ところで、WooCommerceのバージョンが古くないですか？もし、過去のバージョンのテンプレートを使用
しているテーマを利用してるなら、

Comment: > 上記のように2言語仕様に変更してみましたが、やはりデフォルトしか表示されず、でした。 とありますが、編集する箇所が間違っているなどはないですよね?(例えば当該部分を丸々消したら消えますよね?)

Comment: 当該部分を消せば普通に消えます。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ざっくりと気になる部分と
お急ぎっぽいので発想をかえて力技を（後で修正必須ですが汗汗汗）

適用できていないのは
$localeのスコープが関係していそうな気もしますが
前述回答でご提示のあった下記ソースはお試しいただけましたでしょうか。

```
$locale = get_locale();
if ( $locale === 'ja' ) {
    //日本語のテンプレート
} else {
    //元のテンプレート
}
```

呼び出す直前でもget_localeで
呼び出している点を確認してみてください。
$localeの中身などももし確認していないようでしたらvar_dump()などで
ちゃんと値が表示されるか確認するといいかもしれません。

---

javascript等使える方がいればという前提で
かなり力技ですがヘッダでは分岐ができているとのことなので
ヘッダの分岐プラスログインページのみ分岐を分けるという方法はどうでしょうか。

```
<?php $locale = get_locale(); ?>
<?php if ('ja' == $locale ) : ?>
    <?php $slug_name = $post->post_name;
　　　　　　　　if ($slug_name === 'loginpage' ) : ?>
              <!--dom等で日本語の記述をねじ込むjavascript-->
    <?php else: ?>
              //デフォルト
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php else: ?>
    <?php $slug_name = $post->post_name;
　　　　　　　　if ($slug_name === 'loginpage' ) : ?>
              <!--dom等で英語の記述をねじ込むjavascript-->
    <?php else: ?>
    //セカンダリ
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

もしほかのプラグインなどの干渉が原因でしたら
他のプラグインの停止で動くかどうか、
ソースの部分のみをデバックするなら
単純にphpファイルのみを作ってテストできる環境などがあれば
デバックしやすいかと思います。

Comment: こちらの記述で実装出来ました…！プラグインの干渉などもないようです。プラグイン開発元には引き続き情報をコミットしていきます。前述回答で頂いた記述も、試行済みでした。今回頂いた記述ですが、タグが毎行がっつり入れられてることから、前述のソースよりも確実な記述ということになるんでしょうか？

Comment: 特にやっていることはかわらないですね。if文の入れ子を三項演算子を使って記述した形です。三項演算子は間にhtmlやjsをねじ込めるので、(phpの中にも頑張れば入れれると思いますが。)今回heada.phpで判別が動いていてphpでだめだったらjsならどうかということで書いてみました。（お急ぎとの旨も拝見したので）が、前述回答いただいているやり方のほうがスマートですし、何よりメンテナンス性や今後の拡張などを考えてもこのやり方はお勧めいたしません。あくまでも後日変更ということで進めたほうがいいと思いますm(_)m

Answer (score 0):

phpは専門外ですが、国際化対応のライブラリとして有名なgettextが[phpにも標準で実装されているようです](http://php.net/manual/ja/book.gettext.php)。独自実装よりも確実と思いますので、直接の回答ではありませんが参考までに。

Comment: ありがとうございます、チェックしてみます。

Answer (score 0):

多言語対応とのことなので多言語プラグインを既に利用されているのでしょうか。

> デフォルト言語で表示されてしまっています。（サイト内でこの文言だけ）

当該の部分の文言を変えているけど対応している翻訳ファイルがない、ということですかね。

ならば、テキストドメイン(woocommerceになっている部分)を変え、独自の翻訳ファイル(po/mo)をPoEdit等で作り、`load_plugin_textdomain`でそれを読み込みます。

---

### 仮説：テーマ内にWooCommerceプラグインからコピペされた部分がある

WooCommerce自体は最新だけれども当該コピペが古い場合、この問題が発生しうるはずです。
当該部分を最新の

```
<p><?php
    /* translators: 1: user display name 2: logout url */
    printf(
        __( 'Hello %1$s (not %1$s? <a href="%2$s">Sign out</a>)', 'woocommerce' ),
        '<strong>' . esc_html( $current_user->display_name ) . '</strong>',
        esc_url( wc_logout_url( wc_get_page_permalink( 'myaccount' ) ) )
    );
?></p>

<p><?php
    printf(
        __( 'From your account dashboard you can view your <a href="%1$s">recent orders</a>, manage your <a href="%2$s">shipping and billing addresses</a> and <a href="%3$s">edit your password and account details</a>.', 'woocommerce' ),
        esc_url( wc_get_endpoint_url( 'orders' ) ),
        esc_url( wc_get_endpoint_url( 'edit-address' ) ),
        esc_url( wc_get_endpoint_url( 'edit-account' ) )
    );
?></p>
```

で置き換えればただしく表示されるでしょうか。

ただし、この事例のようにプラグインの翻訳文字列はそのうち変わるかもしれないので、テキストドメインを流用することは推奨されていません。(テーマの翻訳として持つべき、となります。テーマチェックにも引っかかりますね。)

---

### `gettext`フィルタを利用する

特定の翻訳だけ変えたい場合はフィルタを用いてコードで書くことも可能です。

https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/gettext

```
add_filter( 'gettext', function ( $translated_text, $text, $domain ) {
    if ( 'woocommerce' === $domain && 'Hello %s%s%s (not %2$s? %sSign out%s)' === $text && 'ja' === get_user_locale() ) {
        $translated_text = 'こんにちは、%1$s%2$sさん%3$s (%2$sさんではない場合は%4$sログアウト 　%5$s)';
    }

    return $translated_text;
}, 20, 3 );
```

Comment: 当該部分は自分では触った事はなく、変更したい言語の翻訳ファイルは存在します。バージョンアップ前からこの箇所は翻訳されていない状態でした。頂いたソースについては、現在がっつりソース編集中でプラグインの更新が出来ていないため、バージョンアップ後に試させてください。今のバージョンでやりましたが表示崩れになってしまいました。

Comment: 当該箇所はWooCommerceのプラグイン内ですか? プラグインや配布されているテーマの直接の編集は避けましょう。プラグイン/テーマをアップデートできない原因となり重大なセキュリティリスクにつながる恐れがあります。(フックやテーマ内へのテンプレートの設置などで対応できるはずなのでそっちを使いましょう。)

Answer (score 0):

おそらく該当するコードは[こちら](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/07932b443284edaefaecada9c2519a15a7ea5314/templates/myaccount/dashboard.php#L26-L42)だと思うので、その前提で回答させていただきます。また、直接プラグインを書き換えることはないと思いますが、テンプレートをオーバーライドできるので念のため。

> This template can be overridden by copying it to　yourtheme/woocommerce/myaccount/dashboard.php.

<del>まず、セカンダリ言語が表示されない理由として、[_e関数](https://wpdocs.osdn.jp/%E9%96%A2%E6%95%B0%E3%83%AA%E3%83%95%E3%82%A1%E3%83%AC%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B9/_e)が使われてないからだと考えます。</del>
コメントで指摘の通り翻訳用の関数は呼ばれていました。

#### 解決の提案1

テンプレートをオーバーライドしその中で_eを使い翻訳対応する。別途翻訳作業が必要になりますが、汎用性が高く対応言語が増えた場合でも楽だと思います。またコミュニティ還元したら喜ばれるかもしれません。

#### 解決の提案2

テンプレートをオーバーライドしその中で言語ごとにテンプレートを分岐させる。具体的には

```
$locale = get_locale();
if ( $locale === 'ja' ) {
    //日本語のテンプレート
} else {
    //元のテンプレート
}
```

などとしてはいかがでしょう。単純に楽だと思います。

#### おまけ

今回は適用できませんが、Wordpressには[Action/Filter フック](https://wpdocs.osdn.jp/%E3%83%97%E3%83%A9%E3%82%B0%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3_API#.E3.83.95.E3.83.83.E3.82.AF.E3.80.81.E3.82.A2.E3.82.AF.E3.82.B7.E3.83.A7.E3.83.B3.E3.81.A8.E3.83.95.E3.82.A3.E3.83.AB.E3.82.BF)があり、Woocommerceでもいくつか用意されています。場合によってはそこに処理を書くこともできるので参照してみてください。
[woocommerce/wc-template-hooks.php at c980817f6df900e3f13095930b0bd445fff01faa · woocommerce/woocommerce](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/c980817f6df900e3f13095930b0bd445fff01faa/includes/wc-template-hooks.php)

Comment: __が使われているので`_e`が使われてない、ではないですね。(`_e`は`echo __` のただのショートカットです)もちろんプラグインを直接書き換えるべきではないです:)。

Comment: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.7/src/wp-includes/l10n.php#L246 を見ると、translate()をechoしてると思うので、

Comment: 何れにしても、translete()が呼ばれていないことが原因かと思います。

Comment: __がtranslateを呼び出してます

Comment: 具体的な策をありがとうございます。最終的には、対処療法ではない提案1のようなやり方でまとめたいと考えていますが、自分の力量が追いつかず提案2に留まりそうな感じがしています。頂いた情報、参考にさせて頂きます。

Comment: @hinaloe ご指摘の通り__もtranslateを呼び出していますね、失礼しました。

Comment: @andre 是非ご参照を。[自分の質問に誰かが回答してくれたらどうしたらいいですか? - ヘルプ センター - スタック・オーバーフロー](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)